# Google Map Bug, Dragend Event also trigger Click Event in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have found that dragend event in Google Map also trigger the click event in IE. It is OK in Firefox and Chrome. Open IE/FF/Chrome console and see the result of this fiddle. Any workaround will be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/ABqMH/8/

Bug Submitted at [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4072&thanks=4072&ts=1334128318#makechanges).

Comment: Note. I need a quick workaround. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a quick workaround

```
var map;
var elevator;
var dragged = false;
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.87916, -3.32910),
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
};
map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], myOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(46.87916, -3.32910),
    draggable: true
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
    console.log('dragend');
    dragged = true;
    setTimeout(function(){ dragged = false; }, 200);
        });
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (evt) {
if (dragged) return;
console.log('click')
});
```

Comment: Submited the bug here, http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4072&thanks=4072&ts=1334128318#makechanges